# React map and filter useState

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript

I need to filter all the vacations I have by vacations the user liked (this user).
I'm trying to do so with a button to check if it works, but id does nothing.
Any hints on how to do it? Tried a few ways already and failed, started thinking about sending by click to mySQL and bring data but it's another headache.
The code:

```
 import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
 import UserModel from "../../../Models/UserModel";
 import VacationModel from "../../../Models/VacationModel";
 import { authStore } from "../../../Redux/AuthState";
 import { vacationsStore } from "../../../Redux/VacationState";
 import notifyService from "../../../Services/NotifyService";
 import vacationService from "../../../Services/VacationsService";
 import useVerifyLoggedIn from "../../../Utils/useVerifyLoggedIn";
 import Spinner from "../../SharedArea/Spinner/Spinner";
 import AdminVacationCard from "../AdminVacationCard/AdminVacationCard";
 import VacationCard from "../VacationCard/VacationCard";
 import "./VacationList.css";

 function VacationList(): JSX.Element {

  useVerifyLoggedIn();

let user: UserModel = authStore.getState().user;

const [vacations, setVacations] = useState<VacationModel[]>([]);

useEffect(() => {

    if (user?.roleId === 2) {
        vacationService.getVacationsForUsers(user.userId)
            .then(vacations => setVacations(vacations))
            .catch(err => notifyService.error(err));
    }
    else {
        vacationService.getAllVacations()
            .then(vacations => setVacations(vacations))
            .catch(err => notifyService.error(err));
    }

    const unsubscribe = vacationsStore.subscribe(() => {
        let duplicateVacations = [...vacations];
        setVacations(duplicateVacations);
    });
    return () => unsubscribe();

}, []);

return (
    <div className="VacationList">

        {vacations.length === 0 && <Spinner />}

        <div className="Cards">

            {user?.roleId === 2 && <>
                {vacations.map(v => <VacationCard key={v.vacationId} vacation={v} />)}
            </>}

            <button onClick={() => vacations.filter(v => v.isFollowing).map(v => 
            <VacationCard key={v.vacationId} vacation={v} />)}>Check</button>

            {user?.roleId === 1 && <>
                {vacations.map(v => <AdminVacationCard key={v.vacationId} vacation={v} 
               />)}
            </>}
        </div>
    </div>
    );
  }

 export default VacationList;
```

This is the list that I show my cards (props).
Thank you!

Comment: Unrelated, but doing the role check on the client side seems... risky.

Comment: Right now your `filter` filters, maps, and throws the result away. The filter should update the list of viewable vacations.

Comment: I check role to show different menus and buttons nothing more than that.
About the filter, so how should I write  it to filter it correctly and show the right card?

Comment: The role also determines who’s vacations are retrieved. You’d filter and set the list of vacations.